# SplitViewController check if detailView is shown

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

Been trying to check if the detailView is being presented in a splitViewController. This is on a iPhone in portrait mode so only 1 view is being shown on the screen. I need to present a modal with contextual actions for the detailview but I need to check that the detail view is actually presented.

So far I have tried:

```
if splitViewController.isCollapsed == false { 
    //  .. always true regardless if im in the master view or detail so doesn't help
}

if splitViewController.displayMode == .primaryHidden {
    print("Detail view is visible")
    // Doesn't return true in detailView
}
```

Is there some other way of checking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out like this by trying to log all the things:

```
print(splitViewController.childViewControllers[0]) // UINavigationController
let navigationcontroller = splitViewController.childViewControllers[0] as! UINavigationController

print(navigationcontroller.visibleViewController) // MasterViewController
```